# Multiple actions ～たり　～たり　する

Tags: grammar

All of the examples and questions I have seen are of the form A～たり　B～たり　する. But is it possible to use たり with three or more actions, such as **A～たり　B～たり　C～たり　する**?

For example, does the following sentence make sense?

> 週末に、友だちに会ったり、日本語の勉強をしたり、本を読んだりします。

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your example is correct. When listing two or more actions, you can use the form A~たり、B~たり、C~たりする like:

> 昨夜は食べたり、飲んだり、騒いだりした。 / We ate, drank and spreed last night.

By the way, it would be better to pay attention not to write as follows:

> 週末に、友達に会ったり、日本語の勉強をする。 △

Some Japanese people write as above and we can understand its meaning, but it is incorrect in terms of the usage of たり.

> 週末に、友達に会ったり、日本語の勉強をしたりする。 〇

We shouldn't omit the たり from second and third action.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, I think it's absolutely fine for enumerating saying (A~, B~, C~, X~...)たり. There are idiomatic phrases 行ったり来たり(to and fro), 願ったり叶ったり（That's what I wished for) saying only A~たりB～たり structure though, you can continue more than two in listing.